# Triple boot - Windows, macOS, Ubuntu - should I use SSD + 2 HDD?

Tags: macos, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

So far, I had been using Windows 10 Pro as my primary OS and using macOS and Ubuntu via VMware.
But, since I'm planning to record videos of macOS and Ubuntu, and I want to record them in the highest possible quality - I thought about using my SSD to boot into Windows, and use my other 2 HDDs to load macOS and Ubuntu.
Note: Each storage device has a capacity of about 1 TB.
To get the full specifications of my storage devices, you can visit my [Steam profile's description](https://steamcommunity.com/id/avi12).

I'm inexperienced with more than single-booting an OS.
Should I do this? If so, what's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: We can't recommend any way to do this, as macOS is not supported on non-Apple hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Boot device and primary `OS`'s storage has nothing to do with video quality.
`HD` video requires lots of free space. You can move your `VM`'s storage images to `SSD` (for `I/O` speed) and store recorded videos to physical `HDD` that has a lot of free space.

By the way, since you are talking about macOS in a virtual machine, I assume you are using Intel-based non-`Apple`'s hardware (Hackintosh) for it with a patch for `VMWare`, which is

- forbidden by both `VMWare`'s and `Apple`'s `macOS` user agreements
- is already tricky to run because of absence of `Apple`'s `EFI` and drivers.

It would be even harder to maintain triple-boot configuration and especially handle updates. Do you really want to repartition all your storage? There are various schemes like `grub2` as main bootloader that launches `Linux` and either `Clover` bootloader for `macOS` or `Windows's bootloader` for `Windows`, but they are unstable.

What I wanted to say is that it is already time-consuming to create this configuration and it's a real pain to keep `macOS` up-to-date with this. You should probably stick to `VM`s as it will save you a lot of time, especially if you create regular snapshots and revert to them in case of problems. If you do not game on `macOS` or `Linux` and do not connect specific hardware to them, `VM` is your best bet.

P.S. It it a lot easier to use `macOS` host on `MacBook` and run `Windows` and `Linux` guests on `Parallels` or `VMWare Fusion`. This way you can use built-in QuickTime to record all your `OS`s.

Comment: As I said, I primarily use Windows, I.e. I use it on daily basis. I thought of the idea of triple-booting because from my experience, running an OS via a virtual machine has less performance than running the OS by directly loading it to a hard drive. Similarly,  it's like saying "I'll use a virtual machine to install a game/software" instead of just mounting the ISO file to a virtual hard drive and installing the software to your hard drive directly. Obviously, you'll get much smoother experience when not using a VM to use the game/software.

Comment: I run `macOS` host and `Windows 8.1` guest with `Visual Studio`, several databases and graphic software - these together consume a lot more resources than any game (apart from pure graphics aka FPS) and I could say that there is no noticeable lags or freezes. If you store your `VM`s on `SSD`, you performance would be more than adequate.

Comment: Again, I am saying that you would not see the difference if you configure your `VM`s and host in a proper way.